# Como puedo usar una variable de otra funcion en Python?

Tags: python, funciones

estoy aprendiendo a programar con python pero tengo problemas para usar una variable de una funcion en otra.
Seria que yo quiero usar la variable duracion de funcion1seg  y mostrarla en la funcion2seg

```
  def funcion1seg(opcion2):  
    duracion1 = int(input("Ingrese el tiempo en segundos: "))  
    while opcion2 == 1:  
        duracion = int(input("Ingrese el tiempo en segundos: "))  
        duracion = duracion + duracion1  
        opcion2 = int(input("Ingrese 1 para seguir sumando o  
        cualquier otro numero para salir: "))  
  
  def funcion2seg(opcion2):  
      print(duracion)
```

Sino si hubiera una manera de pasar los datos duracion1 y duracion a la fuuncion2seg tambien me serviria

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer exactamente? ¿Podrías ser un poco más claro con tu código? primero explica que quieres que haga el código y por que quieres usar una variable de otra función

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si lo que quieres hacer es usar una variable de otra funcion tendras que hace esto

```
def funcion1seg(opcion2):  
    duracion1 = int(input("Ingrese el tiempo en segundos: "))  
    while opcion2 == 1:  
        global duracion #haz la variable "Duracion" global
        duracion = int(input("Ingrese el tiempo en segundos: "))  
        duracion = duracion + duracion1  
        opcion2 = int(input("Ingrese 1 para seguir sumando o cualquier otro numero para salir: "))  
  
  def funcion2seg(opcion2):  
      print(duracion)
```

Cuando una variable se hace asi:

```
var=True
```

La variable es global, es decir que la podes usar en cualquier parte del script
Pero si haces esto:

```
def CreateVar():
    var=True
```

La variable es local
Si quieres que una variable local se convierta en lugar, basta con agregar
global var

```
def CreateVar():
    global var  
    var=True
```

es importante que uses "global" antes de definir la variable, si no, te dara error

PD:
No uses asi global:

```
global var
def globalvar():
    var=True
```

Si lo usas, hazlo en la misma funcion

Te invito a realizar el [Recorrido de bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) Y ganar tu 2da medalla

Comment: @mts_gln si te sirvio dale a la palomita

Answer (score 1):

> Esta sería una forma, espero ayudarte

```py
menu_options = {
    1: 'Ingresar un dato',
    2: 'salir',
}
def ImprimirMenu():
    for key in menu_options.keys():
        print (key, '--', menu_options[key] )

def funcion1seg():
    duracion = 0 # se inicia en 0 para ir sumando cada que entre en el while
    while True:
        ImprimirMenu() # llamamos a la funcion imprimir menu
        option = int(input('Ingresa una opción: '))

        if option == 1:
            duracion2 = int(input("Ingrese el tiempo en segundos: "))
            duracion += duracion2 # sumamos la duracion que se ingreso
        else:
            break #salimos del bucle infinito
    return duracion # retornamos el dato duracion al finalizar el while

def funcion2seg():
      """
      Para usar la variable duracion aqui llamamos a la
      funcion funcion1seg() como se muestra:
      """
      duracion = funcion1seg()
      print(duracion)

# Bloque principal
if __name__ == '__main__':
    funcion2seg()
```

> salida

```
1 -- Ingresar un dato
2 -- salir
Ingresa una opción: 1
Ingrese el tiempo en segundos: 2
1 -- Ingresar un dato
2 -- salir
Ingresa una opción: 1
Ingrese el tiempo en segundos: 3
1 -- Ingresar un dato
2 -- salir
Ingresa una opción: 2
5
```